# How to get only hours and minutes from phpmyadmin CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a form where you can fill out Firstname, Lastname etc. And the information will get sent to a database along with the date (yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss). In my table it will display the full date but i only want it to display the hours and seconds. But year, month etc. in the database.

So how do i only fetch the hours and minutes from the database and display it in a table?

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <th>dato</th>
    <th>Båtnr</th>
    <th>Fornavn</th>
    <th>Etternavn</th>
    <th>Tid</th>
    <th>Kr</th>
</tr>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $sok = @$_POST['searchh'];
    $sql = "SELECT dato, baatnr, fornavn, etternavn, tid, kr FROM utleie WHERE baatnr     LIKE '%$sok%' or fornavn LIKE '%$sok%' or etternavn LIKE '%$sok%' or tid LIKE     '%$sok%'";
    $result = $conn-> query($sql);

if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>". 
        $row["dato"] ."</td><td>".
        $row["baatnr"] ."</td><td>". 
        $row["fornavn"] ."</td><td>". 
        $row["etternavn"] ."</td><td>". 
        $row["tid"] ."</td><td>". 
        $row["kr"] ."</td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
```

database date [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTdaN.png)

Comment: FWIW: You are not getting the values `from phpmyadmin` but from your `mysql database`. phpmyadmin is just a tool to administrate mysql databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it without any change from database side.
you can use php `date` function to manipulate it like:

```
while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".  
        date('H:i',strtotime($row["dato"])) ."</td><td>".
```

this will convert your database date to HH:mm format.

Answer (score 0):

use [`date_format()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) of mysql

`date_format(column,'%h:%i') as column`

Comment: so for example $date = date_format(dato,'%h:%i') as column

Comment: no is a query `select date_format(column,'%h:%i') as column from tb`

Comment: Ok, so i got the hours and minutes from phpmyadmin showed but how to i transport them into the table?

Comment: You did as your regular procedure echo the column name.`column` is just reference string.you could use as per your table date column name

Answer (score 0):

You can use time() function for getting the current hour and minutes:

```
echo date('H:i');
```

Comment: oops, my bad I thought it was just php

Answer (score 0):

You will have to split your date value which you will get from the query result.
For splitting the date in hours and minutes you can use the **explode** function.

Ex :

```
<?php

$date = '2016-08-01 17:56:18';

$hours_minutes = explode(" ",$date);

print_r($new);

echo "hours =".$hours_minutes[1];

//Output hours =17:56:18
```

Here I have splitted the date field using " " (space) and fetched the second value of array.

Note : this will be handled on the php end and not on the database part because in your database you have already inserted the value in timestamp format.

Comment: It will output 17:56:18 but i want it to fetch the data from the database and then display only the hours and minutes into the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = '2016-08-01 17:56:18';
$var = strtotime($date);

echo date('H:i',$var);
```

or

```
echo date('H:i',strtotime('2016-08-01 17:56:18'));
```

Hope This Help

Comment: But the date is already set in the database. So ill do $date = "SELECT dato FROM utleie"; ? and then to the rest that you typed?

Comment: yes you can fetch current_timestamp form database in $date variable and do the rest.